# Finding total time it takes for dataframe write in ADLS path?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I write 100+ dataframes in a loop. How do I log the total duration a single dataframe took to write a CSV in ADLS path?
I would like to store this information in a table where I can check which dataframe needs an optimization.

Sample code to write a TSV to Datalake path:

```scala
dataFrame
      .repartition(1)
      .write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("sep", colDelim)
      .option("quoteAll", true)
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .save(filePath + fileName)
```

Comment: sparkSession.time(processDataFrame) Executes some code block and prints to stdout the time taken to execute the block. try to test it and check how to save the output into a val 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#time-scala.Function0-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you can use below pyspark code for getting duration of each dataframe write operation.

I am assuming you are having list of dataframes.

```
import time

log = []

for i,df in  enumerate(dataframe_list):
    start_time = time.time()
    
    df.repartition(1).write.format("csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("sep", " ") \
    .option("quoteAll", "true") \
    .option("escape", "\"") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save("/mnt/csv/dataframe_"+str(i))
    
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    
    each_df_time = {
    "DF_name":"dataframe"+str(i),
    "time_taken":duration
    }
    log.append(each_df_time)
    
log_df = spark.createDataFrame(log,schema="DF_name STRING, time_taken DOUBLE")
display(log_df)
```

Output:

[image]